# How can I create a MySQL connection using Ionic?

Tags: mysql, ionic-framework

I'm new in Ionic. In my app I want to create a database connection and list something from the database.

How to connect this application with my MySQL database?

Comment: This is possible with node js and angular1. It is not possible without node or any backend programming. But If you want to store it in mobile sqlite, you need not to connect to mysql

Comment: run my app successfully..But now now i want to connect with mysql database.can u please tell me the connection.

Comment: Ionic is for mobiles but I don't know why you want to connect to PC database

Comment: Do you want to develop mobile app or web app using ionic?

Comment: Finally, if you want to develop mobile app, then you need to store data in `webSQL` of the browser. That will be stored in sqlite database in mobile when we install the app in mobile.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script>
    var db;
    var version = 1.0;
    var dbName = "tizendb";
    var dbDisplayName = "tizen_test_db";
    var dbSize = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
    try {
      db = openDatabase(dbName, version, dbDisplayName, dbSize, function(database) {
        alert("database creation callback");
      });
    } catch(e){
      console.log(e)
    }
  </script>
```

This is normal javascript. Use it in your code, after code execution, press F12->Application->webSQL  click on arrow symbol left to webSQL. You will see a database called `tizendb`. that means database created successfully. After that follow this https://developer.tizen.org/development/tutorials/web-application/w3chtml5supplementary-features/storage/web-sql-database

Answer (score 0):

Ionic is meant for mobile front end development. And mysql database would be on server. If you want to use mysql as database for ionic app what you can do is to create a php file which create connection and fire query and all related things. And you can make call to that PHP( or any server side language could be used) with http request from ionic and php file will interact and do process of database and will return response to http which can be used in ionic .

Comment: yeah.. i need the same thing..i strted the coding in js file.where can i save the php file?

Comment: Do you have any server where mysql is installed ?

Comment: yeah.i need to integrate the same in codeigniter.then very easy to connect.But confusion in folder structure

Comment: If yes then put php file there as http://example.com/server/fetchConnection.php $http will makerequest on that path and  fetchConnection.php will do all processing and return response.

Comment: Bro, what will you do in the mobile? Is there any mysql database in mobile? You are just saying that it to work with mysql. But when build finished and he would deploy it in mobile, then he want to create a database in mobile. Is it possible with your answer, php file etc.

Comment: My opinion is there is no use to connect with mySQL DB if you are building a mobile app. there is only one db in mobile that is sqlite. you have to access it and store. For that my suggestion is access webSQL of browser and store the data, that is same thing like accessing sqlite in mobile. So, it will work

Comment: @CharanCherry if we call a $http request for php file(hosted on some server) from a mobile app would not it give response? i think thats how apis are made and work.